# Creating ArcGIS markers (North Arrows) for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, svg, license, inkscape, north-arrow

I came across a PDF containing dozens of north arrows used in Esri's ArcGIS.

QGIS doesn't have many fascinating north arrows, to be candid.

I thought of creating SVG icons of these north arrows and uploading them online for QGIS users. It will also be useful for folks who use vector graphics software like Inkscape.

Is it legal and ethical for me to recreate these icons for QGIS?

Comment: Unless their license permits so, you should not do that.

Comment: This is a legal question. It needs to be asked of a lawyer.

Comment: I was going to say, Yes please! But I think the others are right about the license/copyright implications, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know where ESRI got its arrows but these sites have similar if not the same and many more north arrows: https://www.shutterstock.com/search/north+arrow and https://thenounproject.com/term/north-arrow/283030/

Answer (score 2):

I think the simple answer is no.

Unless directly stated in a license agreement and released to the public domain the north arrows would be under Esri copyright.

Comment: Here is a magnetic north symbol generator for use in qgis https://mdd.sharedgeo.org/